# Sum two array rows in PHP on a single line

Tags: php, matrix, sum, row, array-map

I remember once I came across some website where sum of 2 arrays items was performed on a single line using array_sum and array_map functions. Does anyone know how to do that?

```
$a=array(1,2,3,4,5);
$b=array(0,1,0,1,0);
$result=compoundedSinlgeLineFunction($a,$b);
$result=array(1,3,3,5,5); //this is what we get
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$result = array_map("array_sum", $a, $b);
```

Result: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/M8Zta))

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: array_sum() expects exactly 1 argument, 2 given
```

Comment: In the end I found I need either 2 or 3 operands, so I used my own function, but I did it the same way

Answer (score 0):

I found I might need to sum up 3 numbers as well, so I did that this way, but it's essentially the same as the solution above

```
$z = array_map('sum', $z, $y, $x);

function sum($x, $y, $z=NULL){
  if($z) return $x + $y + $z;
  else return $x + $y;
}
```